# Why is my DbContext DbSet null?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, ef-code-first

I created a new Entity Frameworks Code First app and the DbSet (People) is returning null.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Repository : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People;
}
```

**web.config**: connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Repository"
       connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Repository.sdf"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Now when I call

```
Repository _repo = new Repository()
_repo.People;
```

`_repo.People` will be null

What I am missing?

- Microsoft.Data.Entity.Ctp.dll is
  referenced
- I have tried with and
  without a database initializer.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

That's because you define a *field* of `DbSet<Person>` on Repository class instead of a *property*. Once you add a property or change it to be a automatic property,`People` will start to give you values instead of null. So all you need to do is to change your Repository class to:

```
public class Repository : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It can also come up null if you try to use `{ get; private set; }`.  EF doesn't like that.

Comment: Nor should the setter be protected. It should be public: `{ get; set; }`

Comment: If the data source is a SQL view, can I skip the setter?

Comment: Also, the access modifier *must* be public

Answer (score 51):

I just had the same issue. The problem was that I did set these properties as 'internal' while they must have been 'public'. Just in case someone is still searching :)

Comment: anyone know why you can set them to internal at all?

Comment: @GuyLowe Because a db context is just another class. C# analysers haven't always been clever enough to flag these things as warnings. Now I'm wondering whether the same issue exists in .NET Core/EF Core.

Answer (score 5):

> I just had the same issue. The problem was that I did set these properties as 'internal' while they must have been 'public'. Just in case someone is still searching :)

I guess, these properties can be internal/public too, if you use them like this:

```
public class Repository : DbContext
{
    internal DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    public Repository()
    {
        //your code here...
        People = Set<Person>();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a very clever way to have the best of both worlds. Thanks