# How to add CSV reader "records" to database?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am currently building a .NET service that takes a CSV file, parses it, and stores the parsed data into the database. I've already built the parse logic using CSVhelper. I am fairly new to Backend languages and cannot figure out how to store the data into the database. There isn't a lot of code, but I know i'm making a mistake somewhere.

Parse Service code:

```
public void ReadMonitoredEvent( IFormFile file)
{
    MonitoredEvent monitoredEvent = new MonitoredEvent();

    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream());
    var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader);
    var records = csvReader.GetRecords<MonitoredEvent>();

    this.dbContext.MonitoredEvents.Add(monitoredEvent);
    this.dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I've tried changing out the parameters for the "this.dbContext.MonitoredEvent...." but can't seem to find the proper entity to put as parameters

---

I tested in Postman without the dbContext part and I get a successful 200 code returned, but with the dbContext statements I am getting:

> "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object."

at line: `this.dbContext.MonitoredEvents.Add(monitoredEvent);`

If someone can help me get this sorted out so I can store it into my database I'd appreciate it. I already have my entity model built and all the headers in the CSV match up.

Comment: If you are new with c#, I would suggest using Dapper instead of Entity Framework. They are both wrappers around ado.net, but dapper doesn't have all the craziness that Entity Framework does and is actually much faster in most cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my DbContext DbSet null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270794/why-is-my-dbcontext-dbset-null)

Comment: Also, the problem you are having is that you are never assigning anything to monitored event, you are assigning to records.

Comment: @dmoore1181 That seems to be a mistake in the code indeed (unless the OP assigns it back to `monitoredEvent` later on) but that probably has nothing to do with the NullReferenceException they're getting since `monitoredEvent` is initialized.

Comment: Where is dbContext instantiated? There should be something like `var dbContext = new someContext();`, once it's done you can call use dbContext, otherwise you'll keep getting null reference exceptions.

Comment: @dmoore1181 well whenever I put records into the parameter to add to the db it says "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<StockCheck.Data.Entities.MonitoredEvent>' to 'StockCheck.Data.Entities.MonitoredEvent' "

Comment: @Coke I have " private ApplicationDbContext dbContext;" outside my method

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed no my dbSet { get; set; } is already made

Comment: @BobbyWidThaTool, have you tried using `AddRange`?

Comment: @dmoore1181 Yeah I actually tried that write after responding. It fixed the issue for the records.. however I'm still getting the null reference error. Checking to see if the Object is getting mapped at all right now.